# Import CSV file data from FTP server to salesforce?

Tags: scheduled-apex, ftp

My requirement is, I've to import the CSV file data from FTP server to salesforce on daily basis on late night.

My below research about the requirement.

1) [Jitterbit](http://www.jitterbit.com/) application is free but it will not execute scheduled task If my system(computer/laptop) is off. I don't want functionality should affect the system condition.

2) [Skyvia](https://skyvia.com/) and [dataloadr.io](http://dataloader.io/) is the paid application.

3) If we use Dataloader CLI then it will also not run scheduled task if my system is off.

Let me know if I'm missing in my above research.

We are looking for free and which not affect the system  condition on/off.

I'm thinking about, If we write the PHP cron job on FTP server and send the data from Cron job to SF apex class by rest API like PHP integration with SF.

So It can be possible? how can i implement the coding in this scenario? is any coding example.

Please suggest me, If I'm missing something and solution to move forward.

Comment: "1) Jitterbit application is free but it will not execute scheduled task If my system(computer/laptop) is off. I don't want functionality should affect the system condition" This is what we do in our company....Cannot you install Jitterbit in one of your admin machines ?...The sys admin machine should be up all the time

Comment: @ZenSeeker you said about system admin machine means PHPServer of my company? not sure.

Comment: I meant. In your company you can use any machine which would be up all the time. I find it quite hard to imagine a company where a machine is not up all the time. You can install Jitterbit (the free version should be fine) and have it running in the background.  This is what we do in our mid sized company.

Comment: I use Dataloader command line on Amazon Remote desktop free tier. It works as charm and has 99% uptime